# How does get method knows what it needs to return

Tags: java, return

I have a little trouble understanding when can value be returned

For example I will use get and set methods:

In case 1:

Class:

```
public class Debb {
         private String word;
         public void setName(String n){
         word = n;
           }

         public String getName(){
             return word;
           }

         public void say(){
             System.out.println(getName());
             }

           }
```

Main:

```
 public class nebb {
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
       String plane = "plane";


       Debb temp = new Debb();
       temp.setName(plane);
       temp.say();
  }
 }
```

case 2:

Class:

```
       public class lav {
          private String word;
          public void setName(){
                word = "luka";
              }

          public String getName(){
                return word;
              }

          public void say(){
                System.out.println(getName());
                    }
               }
```

Main:

```
public class fav {
     public static void main(String args[]){    

         lav temp = new lav();
         temp.say();
      }
    }
```

I totally understand what happens with case 2 . getName() does'nt have connection with setName() so it does'nt know what to return and i will get null.

but what about case 1 how method getName() knows that it needs to return value of word from setName().

Comment: What do you think `return word` and `word =` means?

Comment: because you called `setName` to set the name, which is not the case in case 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getName()` is returning `word` and you set it  to "plane" with `setName()`.

> I totally understand what happens with case 2 . getName() does'nt have
>   connection with setName() so it does'nt know what to return and i will
>   get null.

actually you've misunderstood this , `getName()` is again returning `word` but in this case since you didn't provide any value for it , it was initialized to the default value of `null`

Answer (score 0):

The class has a field `String` word.

```
private String word;
```

When you say

```
public void setName(String n){
    word = n;
}
```

You are saying

```
public void setName(String n){
    this.word = n;
}
```

And thus your `getName` is accessing the **same** field when it calls

```
public String getName(){
   return this.word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method setter when you set word to  "plane".

```
 public void setName(String n){
     word = n;
       }
```

And the value of word come when you go to get it with getter method

```
 public String getName(){
         return word;
       }
```

Bacuase you refer to same variable. It's good practice to add key `this` in the method like this.

```
  public void setName(String n){
     this.word = n;
       }
```